# Python instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, class, instance

I've been learning how to use Python for the better part of today after giving up on an ugly bash script.

I'm trying to use 2 classes to define a few arrays of objects in which to store some unique strings and integers (1-10). The objects will consist of the following:

```
object[i].user
         .n     # n = i
         .name
         .coords
         .hero
```

(param1, param2, param3) will be different for each object.n and object.user, so I'm trying to use an assignment method that doesn't look like garbage after writing 90 unique strings. Nesting an example I found didn't work, so here's the compromise:

```
class CityBean:
    def __init__(self,name,coords,hero):
        self.name = name
        self.coords = coords
        self.hero = hero

class Castles:
    def __init__(self,user,n):
        self.user = user
        self.n = n
        if self.user == 'user1':
            temp = {
                1:  CityBean( "name1"  , "coord1" , "hero1"),
                ... blah blah blah
                10: CityBean( "name10" , "coord10" , "hero10" )}[self.n]()
        if self.user == 'user2':
            temp = {
                1:  CityBean( "name11" , "coord11" , "hero11" ),
                ... blah blah blah
                10: CityBean( "name20" , "coord20" , "hero20" ) }[self.n]()
        if self.user == 'user3':
            temp = {
                1:  CityBean( "name21" , "coord21" , "hero21" ),
                ... blah blah blah
                10: CityBean( "name30" , "coord30" , "hero30" ) }[self.n]()
        self.name = temp.name
        self.coords = temp.coords
        self.hero = temp.coords
        __del__(temp)
```

I call it with something like this:

```
cities = list( Castles("user2",i) for i in range(1,11) )
```

It gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: CityBean instance has no __call__ method
```

And it blames this line:

```
                10: CityBean( "name20" , "coord20" , "hero20" ) }[self.n]() # pseudo
                10: CityBean( "" , "" , "" ) }[self.n]() # what is actually looks like
```

What's wrong with my cruddy classes? I'm doing something retarded, aren't I?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with `[self.n]()`?

Comment: I was just trying to pick one of the options, not realizing that the parentheses called the result as a function... oops!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really hard to guess what you want from what you provided, since, instead of saying what you want to do, you provided your newbie code, so one has a hard guess time.

I'd think something like this would do:

```
data = {
        (1, 'user1'): ("name1", "coord1", "hero1"),
        (2, 'user1'): ("name2", "coord2", "hero2"),
        #...
        (1, 'user2'): ("name11", "coord11", "hero11"),
        (2, 'user2'): ("name12", "coord12", "hero12"),
        # ...
    }


class CityBean:
    def __init__(self,name,coords,hero):
        self.name = name
        self.coords = coords
        self.hero = hero

class Castles:
    def __init__(self,user,n):
        self.user = user
        self.n = n
        name, coords, hero = data.get((n, user))
        self.citybean = CityBean(name, coords, hero)
```

Comment: +1 I bow before your ability to make sense of the goal of the code in this question.

Comment: @tyblu Note the use of a tuple (1,'user1') as key of the dict. A tuple is immutable and can therefore be used as a key. A list [1, 'user1'] could not be used as a key.

Comment: @extraneon: A tuple, hey... Seems to be an ambiguous name. :) Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Why did your write this?

```
temp = {
            1:  CityBean( "name21" , "coord21" , "hero21" ),
            ... blah blah blah
            10: CityBean( "name30" , "coord30" , "hero30" ) }[self.n]()
```

What do you think `temp= {...}[something]()` will do?

1. It creates a dictionary.  `{...}`
2. It picks one item out of the dictionary.  `{...}[something]`.  This will be a `CityBean` object.
3. It evaluates that one item as a function `{...}[something]()`  Is `CityBean(...)()`

Why are you calling the CityBean object as if it was a function?

Further, why are you creating entire dictionaries only to pick a single item of it?  What's wrong with `if` statements?

Answer (score 2):

your are doing

```
{
1:  CityBean( "name1"  , "coord1" , "hero1"),
... blah blah blah
10: CityBean( "name10" , "coord10" , "hero10" )}[self.n]()
```

which is basically from a dict get value based on key, values on your dict are CityBean instances, so in short you are doing this

```
CityBean( "name1"  , "coord1" , "hero1")()
```

which is valid but will call the special method `__call__` of the instance, so either remove `()` or add a `__call__` method depending on the need

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do exactly, but:

```
 10: CityBean( "name10" , "coord10" , "hero10" )}[self.n]()
```

if calling something (the () at the end make it a function call).

What you would want is I think
    temp = { ...
        10: CityBean( "name10" , "coord10" , "hero10" )}[self.n]

In that case you'd get the dict entry with key n and label that temp.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, that in python, when you write

```
CityBean( "name1"  , "coord1" , "hero1")
```

You initialize the object `CityBean`. There is no need for an extra `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this problem if you do something wrong

```
os.environ("METAG_DATA")
```

The correct way is

```
os.environ["METAG_DATA"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting parens after a class name in a normal expression instantiates it immediately. If you want to delay instantiation then you'll need to use [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) or [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
10: lambda: CityBean("", "", "")}...
```